# How to render an emoji?

Tags: front-end, string-manipulation, character-encoding

Is there any way to get Mathematica to render [emoji's from unicode strings](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)? For instance, ":1F600" should be but it renders as an "oulinded question mark":

[image]

Also, `FromCharacterCode[]` doesn't seem to work either:

```
FromCharacterCode["1F600", "Unicode"]
```

[image]

Comment: I gues you would have to first convert the hex number to an integer: `FromCharacterCode[FromDigits["1F600", 16], "Unicode"]`. But that seems to lie outside the range of UTF glyphs that Mathematica supports...

Comment: When it's possible to render an emoji in the frontend, I expect it will be *very* well publicized how to do it.